# Error when Updating query using PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have set a custom function to update my query however it doesn't seem to read the variables i am not sure where i am going wrong.
This is my function.

```
    function update_product($productID, $productName, $productDescription, $productPrice, $categoryID){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE product SET productName = :productName, productDescription = :productDescription, productPrice = :productPrice, categoryID = :categoryID WHERE productID = :productID";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':productName', $productName);
    $statement->bindValue(':productDescription', $productDescription);
    $statement->bindValue(':productPrice', $productPrice);
    $statement->bindValue(':categoryID', $categoryID);
    $statement->bindValue(':productID', $productID);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result;
}
```

This is where i am calling the function

```
$result = update_product($productID, $productName, $productDescription, $productPrice, $categoryID);
```

I will also add my function where i am getting the ID and loading the inputs...

```
function select_productspreparedGETID(){
global $conn;

$productID = $_GET['id'];

//prepared
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID = :productID";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':productID', $productID);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();

foreach($result as $row):
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="../controller/product_update_process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
          <label>Name* </label>
            <input id="Product_Name" type="text" name="Product_Name" value="<?php echo $row['productName'] ?>" />
      </div>
      <div>
            <label>Description* </label>
            <textarea id="productDescription" name="productDescription" /><?php echo $row['productDescription'] ?></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
              <label>Price* </label>
              <input id="Price" type="text" name="Price" value="<?php echo $row['productPrice'] ?>" />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value= "Update Cart">
  </form>
  <?php
      endforeach;
```

}

Any advice on how to improve my structure or better yet beat this error would be seriously appreciated i have been stuck for the last 20hours.

Comment: What is the actual error text that you're getting?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: productID in C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Xammp\htdocs\Shopping List\controller\product_update_process.php on line 14

Comment: It seems to me $_GET['id'] is not defined (not in the URL query)... you might need to handle this case and assign a default value to productID if $_GET['id'] is not defined... then act accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `$productID = $_GET['id'];` inside a function and using the same variable in another function. The `$productID` is  clearly not available to other functions. Make sure that it is defined outside any functions.

Currently the variable is only available to the local scope in which it is defined. For example, define `$productID` outside any functions:

```
$productID = $_GET['id'];
```

You can send this variable to `select_productspreparedGETID()` as an argument:

```
function select_productspreparedGETID($productID){
    //Your code
}
```

And then you have `$productID` inside both functions `update_product()` and `select_productspreparedGETID()` because `update_product()` already has `$productID` as an argument.

Comment: Silly question but how can i define it outside any function if i need to grab the id to fill forms before it can get updated?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be helping anything just adding another error on all pages with Undefined index: id

Comment: @JackWarren I suppose you are referring to `$_GET['id']`. You need to get id from the URL.

Comment: I am aware of that, but if i am adding $productID = $_GET['id']; outside any function it is going to show an error on any page, unless i need to create an addition functions file for these functions.. will give that a try

Comment: And it was to do with it all on the same page... thanks for your time much appreciated!!